# WatchOS 4 App: CBCentralManager state is always in CBManagerStateUnsupported

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, watchos-4

I'm developing an app for Apple Watch Series 3, and it seems that the state of `CBCentralManager` is always `CBManagerStateUnsupported`.

I'm using the following code:

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    NSString *stateString = nil;
    switch(central.state)
    {
        case CBManagerStateResetting:
            stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.";
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
            stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnauthorized:
            stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
            stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
            stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.";
            [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                         forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]];
            break;
        default:
            stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent.";
            break;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you check the state, is it on simulator or on a Watch?  Also, did you notice that CBCentralManagerState is deprecated on watchOS 4?

Comment: @Cobra Yes I'm check the state on a watch. And CBCentralManagerState is not a deprecated method watchOS.

Comment: The documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerstate?language=objc shows deprecated in watchOS 2-3.  Where are you getting your information?  Ah, never mind, I see the enumeration is the only thing deprecated, not centralManagerDidUpdateState.

Comment: The documentation isn't complete though, as centralManagerDidUpdateState is shown as available, but the returned values are part of the deprecated enum...